# Text normalization in python using Normalizer.Form.NFKD

Tags: java, python-3.x, text, normalization

A field in the table is normalized using Java as shown below,

```
  String name = customerRecord.getName().trim();
  name = name.replaceAll("œ", "oe");
  name = name.replaceAll("æ", "ae");
  name = Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
  name = name.toLowerCase();
```

Now I'm trying to query the same db using Python. How do I do `Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFKD)` in Python so that it is compatible with the way it is written to?

Comment: Please read "[Is “How do I convert code from this language to this language” too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296119/128421)" and "[“Please convert my code to X” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54345)". We want to see your attempt to solve this. SO isn't a code-translation service, but we are happy to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

An almost complete translation of the above Java code to Python would be like as follows,

```
import unicodedata

ASCII_REPLACEMENTS = {
    'œ': 'oe',
    'æ': 'ae'
}

text = ''.join([ASCII_REPLACEMENTS.get(c, c) for c in search_term])

ascii_term = (
    unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).
    encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode()
)


return ascii_term.lower()
```

`ASCII_REPLACEMENTS` should be amended with what ever characters that wont get translated correctly by `unicodedata.normalize` compared to Java's `Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFKD)`. This way we can ensure the compatibility between the two.