# Canot slice/index unicode strings with underscores

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, slice

I have this Unicode string:

```
my_string = "₁ᴀa̲a̲̲"
```

How can index and slice it to make other Unicode strings?

If I run

```
print([x for x in my_string])
['₁', 'ᴀ', 'a', '̲', 'a', '̲', '̲']
```

when I expected

['₁', 'ᴀ', 'a̲', '̲a̲̲']

this prints

```
my_string[3]
'̲'
```

when I expected

```
a̲̲
```

I tried t define

```
my_string = u"₁ᴀa̲a̲̲"
```

but the `u` is automatically deleted by vscode

I need `my_string` as buffer to compose other strings according to his human-readable index.

Comment: maybe you could use normalize your string first with [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)? not sure if that helps....

Comment: @hiro protagonist
I tried `my_string = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",u"₁ᴀa̲a̲̲")`, but it doesn't works for underscored characters.

Comment: should it be `a̲̲`or `a̳`?

Comment: @Andj "a_" and "a__" as shown by  

`print([x for x in my_string])
['₁', 'ᴀ', 'a', '̲', 'a', '̲', '̲']
`
  
I think that stackoverflow mangled the unicode.

Comment: your string is U+0061 U+0332 U+0332, which should render as a with a combining low line below the a, and then another combining low line below the first combining low line. Normally, I'd see U+0061 U+0333 instead. But then I only tend to see U+0332 and U+0333 in real life in bibliographic data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`\X` regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9928505/16343464) and `findall` from the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module:

```
import regex

out = regex.findall(r'\X', my_string)
```

Output:

```
['₁', 'ᴀ', 'a̲', 'a̲̲']
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion expressed in the comments to `normalize` the string is the most viable; however, you may also want to account for `encoding` the characters:

```py
import unicodedata
for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', my_string):
    print("Normalized: " + x)
    print("Encoded: " + str(x.encode('ascii', errors="backslashreplace"))) 
    print("Encoded/decoded: " + x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

You will see the difference:

```
Normalized: ₁
Encoded: b'\\u2081'
Encoded/decoded: 
Normalized: ᴀ
Encoded: b'\\u1d00'
Encoded/decoded: 
Normalized: a
Encoded: b'a'
Encoded/decoded: a
Normalized: ̲
Encoded: b'\\u0332'
Encoded/decoded: 
Normalized: a
Encoded: b'a'
Encoded/decoded: a
Normalized: ̲
Encoded: b'\\u0332'
Encoded/decoded: 
Normalized: ̲
Encoded: b'\\u0332'
Encoded/decoded:
```

### Notes

In response to comments, passing `errors="backslashreplace"` may be a viable solution if the desire is to compare more problematic strings.

Comment: This will discard the composing and non-ascii characters (like `ᴀ`), which doesn't seem to be what is wanted.

Comment: @mozway You have a point there, if the OP's desire is to leverage a fine control over more finicky characters, possibly [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70773028/1655567) could be utilised. Although, this would require hand-mapping of potentially problematic characters.